# Datetime field and validation in Entity Framework code-first approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, datetime

`datetime` field validation and format problems (dd/mm/yyyy).

When I add controller and views of specific model with `datetime` fields with (`dd/mm/yyyy`) format 
but at run time when I select date like (`21/09/2013`) from datepicker and leave focus from control it display validation message

> the field CreateDate must be a date.

Comment: Can you show us your model?

Comment: is the filed of DateTime type? or string? format date can not apply to DateTime but string representation of DateTime

Comment: did u add dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', to your datepicker?

Comment: Looks like a validation message from ASP.NET MVC, not from Entity Framework. I've added the `asp.net-mvc` tag.

Comment: Please don't add code like that in comments... it's impossible to read. Just edit the question and add it there with proper formatting.